# Min function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, min

I am trying to find a division with the lowest population density to do so i did the following:

```
SELECT P.edname, MIN((P.total_area*1000)/P.total2011) AS "Lowest population density"
FROM eds_census2011 P
GROUP BY P.edname
HAVING COUNT (*)> 1
```

`total_area` is multiplied by 1000 (so it is in square metres) and divide by total population.
I want only one record displaying the division (`edname`) and the population density wich is calculated `(MIN((P.total_area*1000)/P.total2011))`, instead I get all the records - not even sorted...

The problem is that I have to group it by edname, if I leave out the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` lines I get an error. Any help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: `multiplied by 1000 (so it is in square metres)` .. That's odd. What would your base unit be? Sqares of 31.623x31.623 meters? Hard to believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT edname, (total_area*1000/total2011) density
  FROM eds_census2011
 WHERE (total_area*1000/total2011) = (SELECT MIN(total_area*1000/total2011) FROM eds_census2011)
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f43ad/4)**

*A 'Return only one row' rule could be easily enforced by using `LIMIT 1` if it's really necessary*

Comment: @AndreiIvanov: This query ignores the `HAVING count(*) > 1` part and is not equivalent. Well, the question is pretty vague about the exact goal.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter OP's goal was to just find the smallest density

Comment: If that's all he wants, your answer is correct, but it could be much simpler, and the Q is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Without subquery:

```
SELECT p.edname, min((p.total_area * 1000)/p.total2011) AS lowest_pop
FROM   eds_census2011 p
GROUP  BY p.edname
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
ORDER  BY 2
LIMIT  1;
```

This one returns only 1 row (if any qualify), even if multiple rows have equally low density.

If you just want the lowest density, period, this can be much simpler:

```
SELECT edname, (total_area * 1000)/total2011) AS lowest_pop
FROM   eds_census2011
ORDER  BY 2
LIMIT  1;
```

Comment: Thank for an answer, but this does not return the smallest density... Maybe because it is still grouped by edname!?

Comment: @AndreiIvanov: I am pretty sure it does. To be precise: the smallest density among those where at least 2 rows for one `edname` exist. That's what `HAVING COUNT (*) > 1` (like in your original query) does.